Discrepancy with summarise and summarise_at results - R language
I have a dataset that looks like this:
a <- data.frame(cat = c("a","b","b","c","a","c"),
           num1 = c(-2,1,2,4,3,2),
           num2 = c(-2,3,1,5,3,2),
           weight = c(3.12,2,14,1.12,1,12))

I'm trying to get a weighted mean for each "num" column (on my real dataset I have many "num" columns, all named the same).
I started coding it like this:
a %>% summarise(num1 = weighted.mean(num1,weight,na.rm=T),
                num2 = weighted.mean(num2,weight,na.rm=T))

Which returns:



num1
num2




1.661853
1.394705



But since I have to process many columns I moved to this way:
a %>% summarise(across(contains("num"), ~weighted.mean(.x,na.rm=T)))

or:
a %>% summarise_at(.vars=vars(contains("num")),
                   function(x,weight) weighted.mean(x,weight))

They both return:



num1
num2




1.666667
2



Why am I getting different results here? Which way should I trust?

It's worth remembering that scoped verbs in the tidyverse have been superseded by across...

You missed weight in your second alternative, try:
a %>% 
  summarise(across(contains("num"), ~weighted.mean(.x, weight, na.rm=TRUE)))
     num1     num2
1 1.661853 1.394705

Here's an alternative for your third approach:
a %>% 
  summarise_at(.vars=vars(contains("num")),
                   function(x,weight) weighted.mean(x, w=.$weight, na.rm=TRUE))
      num1     num2
1 1.661853 1.394705

